# How to fix 'startup__.py' error while opening Cura software?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My 3d printer slicing software were working correctly but recently I installed the latest python package and now this error shows up when I try to open cura. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: error while opening software]

Comment: Why does it try to log to another user folder than it is installed to?

Comment: 'Ali Hussain' is the user which I am working at